# android 4.0.3 ImageSpans overlapping

Tags: android

XML layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</EditText>
```

Insert two ImageSpan:

```
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    et.setText("E\n Toooooooooooooo");

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(et.getText());

    ImageSpan span1 = new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.pintu_joint,
            ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span1, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    ImageSpan span2 = new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.pintu_freedom,
            ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span2, 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    et.setText(ss);
```

The two images overlapping(Sorry, I'm not allowed to post images).

It's ok in android 2.3, but not in 4.0+.

Thanks in advance.